# Online price comparing API(Ebay &Amazon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, amazon-web-services

In my app users lists variety of products/Items with their prices.I want to be able to compare them with online prices(fetch items prices from Amazon & Ebay).Is there any ruby gem or tool for that?I am using Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon has an API, and there's a few gems that work with it. See this conversation: [Amazon Product API and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121642/amazon-product-api-and-rails)

A bit of searching suggests that EBay also has an API, and that there are gems for that as well, although I've not used them. Here's one, with an article explaining use: http://www.codyfauser.com/2006/11/22/ebay-api-client-for-ruby